# Is there any way to set the last used font as the default font in drawio?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

One feature I am missing the most in *drawio* is using the last used font as default font. Now I have to change the font for every cell or object I created, defaulted to **Helvetica** which is so awful to do. Many other online drawing tools have this feature. Is there any way to achieve this in *drawio*?

Comment: OK. I get it. Actually I have to set the font of an object to the preferred font before duplicating . Then I will get the preferred font with new objects also.

Answer (score 0):

Font defaults to whatever the last font set on a cell is.
You can also change the font family and font size on a cell and that will become the default.
​
To clear default styling, ensure nothing is and click "clear default styling" in the right-hand format panel.

Comment: Marija, thank you. So I was creating all the objects at first before writing on them. That was the problem. I get it :)